# Data type error while reading Parquet files in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, types, parquet

I have converted a bunch of CSV files into parquet files, and while trying to load 5 rows of the parquet files into another Pyspark dataframe, I got an error.

How I converted my CSV files into Parquet files:

```
df = spark.read.options(delimiter='|', inferSchema=True).csv(csv_folder, header=True)
df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet("parquet_folder/")
```

How I read the Parquet files:

```
df = spark.read.parquet("parquet_folder/*.parquet")
```

One of the fields, `num_A`, is read as an `integer`, based on the `printSchema` output.

I'm able to run `df.show(5)` successfully, but when I tried to run `test = df.limit(5)`, I got the error message

```
Parquet column cannot be converted in file ... Column: [num_A], Expected: int, Found: INT64
```

If I specify a schema prior to reading the parquet file, i.e.

```
schema = StructType([StructField("num_A", LongType())])
df = spark.read.schema(schema).parquet("parquet_folder/*.parquet")
```

I get the error when running `df.show(5)`:

```
Parquet column cannot be converted in file ...(another parquet file) Column: [num_A], Expected: bigint, Found: INT32
```

It seems like my `num_A` has both `integer` and `long` types, but the schema can only be set to one of them? How can I resolve this without having to rewrite my parquet files with an explicit schema?

Comment: Can you read it as a string then cast it as a long type?

Comment: I tried that, and when I simply tried to do `df.show(5)`, I get the error `Parquet column cannot be converted in file ... Column: [num_A], Expected: string, Found: INT32`